# Нужно ли выделять запятыми слова "чтобы купить продуктов"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Мой дед хочет пойти в магазин, чтобы купить продуктов(?) под предлогом того, что он купит мне котёнка.

Возникло сомнение в месте, где стоит вопросительный знак, насчёт запятой. Если же она там ставится, то можете объяснить почему?

Comment: Предложение не очень удачное. Допустимо для школьного сочинения, но требует переделки, если это рассказ, предназначенный для публикации. Какой уровень требований к этому тексту?

Comment: Ни то ни другое. Это совершенно случайное предложение, услышанное мною при разговоре с другом.

Answer (score 1):

> Мой дед хочет пойти в магазин (под предлогом того, что он купит мне
> котенка), чтобы купить продуктов.

или

> Мой дед хочет пойти в магазин (чтобы купить продуктов) под предлогом
> того, что он купит мне котенка.

Answer (score 1):

Да можно как угодно, но значения будут разные.

*Мой дед хочет пойти в магазин, чтобы купить продуктов под предлогом того, что он купит мне котёнка* — сочетание *под предлогом того* относится к предшествующей придаточной части. Паузы между ними нет;

*Мой дед хочет пойти в магазин, чтобы купить продуктов, под предлогом того, что он купит мне котёнка* — сочетание *под предлогом того* относится к главной части, поэтому отделяем от придаточной.

Comment: Нужно писать не как угодно, а по правилам. Пожалуйста, дайте ссылку.

Comment: @Sharon Какую еще ссылку? Автор решает, относить или нет. А 'как угодно' и означает 'как угодно', но в рамках правил.

Comment: Автор спрашивает, а вы отвечайте, что и почему выбрать. Грамматику определите. И правило назовите. Не надо давать "как угодные" ответы. Давайте работать серьезно! На форуме есть стандарт для хороших ответов.

Answer (score 0):

Оборот "чтобы купить продуктов" ведь надо обособить? Но фраза неудачная, главное - смысл туманный. Дед идет за котенком, а заодно и продуктов купить? Тогда "под предлогом" неуместно. Дед идет за продуктами, а заодно и за котенком? Здесь тоже "под предлогом" стоит неудачно.

Comment: Ну, сомнений быть не должно. )

Answer (score 0):

Правильно:

***Мой дед хочет пойти в магазин**, / чтобы купить продуктов, // **под предлогом того**, / что он купит мне котёнка.*

**Пояснение**

1. **Три предикативные** основы, решаем задачу методом блоков **[по Лопатину §132](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8/)**

   В сложных синтаксических конструкциях, распадающихся
   на крупные логико-синтаксические **блоки**, которые
   сами по себе являются сложными предложениями или в
   которых один из блоков оказывается сложным
   предложением, на стыке блоков ставятся **знаки
   препинания**, указывающие на **взаимоотношения
   блоков,** при сохранении внутренних знаков, поставленных на своем собственном синтаксическом основании:

**Первый** блок — СПП с придаточным цели.  **Второй** блок — **обстоятельственный** оборот, в составе которого придаточное изъяснительное.

2. На границе блоков ставим **запятую**, которая в общем случае является **факультативной** (для обстоятельственных оборотов).
3. Предложение явно делится  **на две части**  по семантике и интонации,  а также по **структуре** предложения (два равные по объему фразы). Именно такое произношение подойдет для **разговорной** речи.
4. Я не вижу здесь **неправильности** самого предложения, а также не считаю, что **варианты** возможны.